# Concatenate large numpy arrays in RAM

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ram, scikit-image

I have some 3D image data and want to build a stack of RGB images out of single channel stacks, i.e. I try to concatenate three arrays of shape `(358, 1379, 1042)` into one array of shape `(358, 1379, 1042, 3)`. Inspired by `skimage.color.gray2rgb` I tried

```
np.concatenate((
    stack1[..., np.newaxis], 
    stack2[..., np.newaxis], 
    stack3[..., np.newaxis]), axis=-1)
```

However, even though each of these stacks is only about 1GiB this fills my empty ~12GiB RAM immediately ... So I tried to pre-allocate an array of the final shape and then fill it with the stacks, like

```
rgb_stack = np.zeros(stack1.shape + (3,))
rgb_stack[:,:,:,0] = stack1
```

which also exhausted my RAM once I execute the second line. Finally I tried to explicitly copy the data from `stack1` into `rgb_stack` by

```
rgb_stack = np.zeros(stack1.shape + (3,))
rgb_stack[:,:,:,0] = stack1.copy()
```

with the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you don't specify a dtype, `zeros` will assume you want float64, and a `(358, 1379, 1042, 3)` float64 array will take up ~11.5 GiB. What dtype are your input arrays?

Comment: That 11.5GiB are about what `whos` tells me -- but in the RAM it seems to be a lot smaller? Anyways, the input arrays are `dtype('uint16')` and I could also go to 8bit.

Comment: Some operating systems (notably Linux) will happily overcommit memory. When you create your array of zeros, the kernel does not immediately set aside a correspondingly sized chunk of RAM - this only occurs when you actually try to write to those memory addresses, hence why you only see the `MemoryError` when you try to assign to `rgb_stack`.

Comment: Do you have the data saved elsewhere? If you do I would try to help python's garbage collector by saying del stack1 after you have put it into the rgb_stack, same thing after stack2 has been inserted.

Comment: Try preallocating a uint16 array rather than a float64 array, e.g. `np.empty(..., dtype=np.uint16)`. It is still odd that your original approach with `np.concatenate` is using so much memory. One possible cause would be if one of your input arrays has a different dtype to the others, causing the output dtype to be promoted up to the largest item size.

Comment: I was also using `np.zeros` as default `stack3` when playing around with `np.concatenate`, sorry for that ... Thanks and good luck with your thesis! ;-)

Comment: Thanks - as you can see it's not going particularly well...

Comment: You may also want to investigate other packages, such as PIMS, xray, bcolz, dask, etc. that can handle chunked data so that you can operate on the entire set of data as one array, but without loading it into a contiguous chunk of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wrap up what can be learnt from the comments to the question; `np.zeros` creates an array of `float64` which is almost 12GiB big. This by itself does not fill the RAM as Linux over commits and only sets the corresponding RAM aside once the array gets filled, which is in this case once it gets filled with the image data.

Thus creating `zeros` as another `dtype` solves the problem, e.g.

```
rgb_stack = np.zeros(stack1.shape + (3,), dtype=np.uint16)
rgb_stack[:,:,:,0] = stack1.copy()
```

works fine with `uint16` stacks.